# How to remove elements with a set range in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list created in Python:

```
list_items=["apple", 2 , 3 , 4 ,"orange", 20 , 41 , 7 ,"banana", 5 , 24 , 5]
```

The question is when I input "apple" I want to remove a range of data from this list, for example, remove "apple" to number 4 in the list only and leave the rest.

Comment: So it is to remove until next `str`? What if you do `orange`? Does it delete `apple` part, too?

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Use a different data structure e.g. `{'apple': [2,3,4], 'orange': [20, 14, 7] ...}`...

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the initial item you want to remove:

```
>>> list_items=["apple", 2 , 3 , 4 ,"orange", 20 , 41 , 7 ,"banana", 5 , 24 , 5]
>>> n = list_items.index('orange')
>>> n
4
```

Then delete the the slice that selects the item range:

```
>>> list_items[n:n+4]    # slice that selects the items
['orange', 20, 41, 7]
>>> del list_items[n:n+4]
>>> list_items
['apple', 2, 3, 4, 'banana', 5, 24, 5]
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
>>> list_items=["apple", 2 , 3 , 4 ,"orange", 20 , 41 , 7 ,"banana", 5 , 24 , 
5]
>>> list_items.remove("apple")
>>> list_items
[2, 3, 4, 'orange', 20, 41, 7, 'banana', 5, 24, 5]
```